# Early usage of Martian meaning inhabitant of Mars

Tags: word-usage, etymology, latin, literature

Martian as an adjective meaning "of, pertaining to, or characteristic of the planet Mars" (originally in reference to astrological influence) is from the 14th century according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/martian);

curiously, according to the same source, the noun meaning "an inhabitant of the planet Mars" has a much later origin, that is attested by 1877.

Though the usage of Martians  to refer to an indigenous population of the planet Mars is quite logical, I wonder where its usage actually originated from. Probably by a 19th century author of a science fiction book, but  I couldn’t  find [any evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Martian%2C%20Martians%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2CMartian%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMartian%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmartian%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMARTIAN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CMartians%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMartians%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMARTIANS%3B%2Cc0) to support this view.

Where does Martian meaning inhabitant of Mars come from? Who first used it?

Comment: Well, an inhabitant would be 'of or pertaining to', wouldn't they? It's just an extension of the original, astrological meaning.

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, that’s what I say in my question. But I am asking about its usage to refer to inhabitant of Mars. Someone in late 19th century called them that way.  Before that, apparently, nobody thought about aliens from Mars and called them Martians.

Comment: So the first person to think of them used the existing word meaning 'of or pertaining to Mars' - which is what I said in my comment.

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, who did it and where did that happen? Was it a science fiction book? My best unsupported guess. An American writer, or a British one? Or neither of them.

Comment: Have you tried Google Ngrams?

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, but I couldn’t  find anything helpful to my question https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Martian%2C+Martians+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2CMartian%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMartian%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmartian%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMARTIAN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CMartians%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMartians%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMARTIANS%3B%2Cc0

Comment: _Martian_ comes straight from Latin: _Mars, Martis, Martianus_ It was used long before English or printing, and long before the novel or science fiction.

Comment: @JohnLawler - are you saying that they used to refer  to aliens living on Mars in ancients times? And they call them Matrianus?

Comment: _Martianus_ is simply a regular Latin adjective that could be used to refer to an inhabitant of Mars, if anyone needed to refer to one. It was available as an English word like most Latin words, and it got used as needed. Nothing to see here, I'm afraid.

Comment: While I'd say this is on-topic here, you might get more responses on say Literature.SE or Science Fiction & Fantasy.SE.

Comment: Great question! Don't let the grumpy people spoil your fun on this site. I see you have already received a pretty good answer, which proves that it is a fine question.

Comment: Sure, this is technically a valid and answerable question. But as others have noted, the answer is likely to boil down to "who was the first person to refer to inhabitants of Mars in English?" Unless you also accept similar words in other languages, in which case it becomes "who was the first person to refer to inhabitants of Mars in Latin or in any other language that inherited or borrowed its planetary names and adjectival suffixes?" (And those questions, in turn, have more to do with the history of literature than with linguistics.)

Comment: You might find [this online historical dictionary of SF terms](https://sfdictionary.com/view/240/martian) interesting. It lists the same 1868 usage as Sven Yargs found, as well as a 1900 citation for Martian referring to a language. Also note that Etymlonline's 15th Century (not 14th) meaning is "of or pertaining to the **god** Mars"; the application to the planet seems to be a 19th Century development.

Comment: At least the name makes sense. If you look at demonyms in French, you find all and everything - it is impossible to derive the name of inhabitants of a country or city from the name of that country or city. It is even a typical question on *Who Wants To Be A Millionaire*-kind of shows when they want to make an answer un-answerable :)

Comment: "Who first used it" isn't answerable, since the first usage was quite possibly spoken. The best you could possibly hope to find is  "Who first used it in a published written document?"

Comment: All martians come from Mars, of course.

Comment: @JEL - the question is not about the first instance of when someone said that Mars had native inhabitants but on the earliest usage of the term “Martians” in that respect. As shown below that may have happened in the second half of the 19th century. Unluckily for  some reason this question has been largely misunderstood, probably I didn’t express clearly enough.

Comment: @JEL - this is about the english language, so are you saying that in the English version of the Old Testament or other ancient writings  they used the specific term “Martian”? That would be interesting to know. I am not interested in other expression that may refer to aliens living on Mars, but just on the term “Martian” in English, not other languages. But probably I am still not clear.

Answer (score 21):

The earliest match that an Elephind newspaper database search finds for *Martians* in the sense of "inhabitants of Mars" is from a compilation of items headed "[Inhabitants of the Sun](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/96875542?searchTerm=Mars+Martians)," in the *[Port Elliott, South Australia] Southern Argus* (November 18, 1869), reprinted from an edition of *Once a Week* of some earlier date:

> A French idealist, evidently suffering from telegraphy on the brain, proposes to the Academy of Sciences to establish communications with the peoples of the planets, if any such there be. His notion is to mount a great mirror upon the earth, and give flashing signals to Mars and Jupiter. He thinks that if these are repeated regularly, in batches of a certain number, the **Martians** or the Jovians, as the cases may be, will come to discern that they mean something, and will return them, and that thus a code will be eventually agreed upon, so that we may talk across the solar system just as we do across a field. This silly man calls attention to the bright spots which have occasionally been seen on some of the planets, and suggests that these were probably signals from the habitants thereof to us. This idea of planetary signalling is an o[d]d one; it has been mooted before, and (doubtle[s]s has occurred to thousands who have not had the effrontery to give their thoughts a tongue. My object in alluding to its present revival is to give an instance of the absurdities tolerated by the Paris Academy of Sciences.—*Once a Week*.

I haven't done a thorough search for instances of singular *Martian* in the sense of "inhabitant of Mars," but *Martians* certainly goes back to at least 1869.

---

Slightly older than the previous example is this instance from "[Historic Progress and American Democracy](https://books.google.com/books?id=RiISAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22martians%22+%22Mars+and+if+inclined+for+a+vacation+excursion%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9i86Z0NnuAhXItp4KHRpXByEQ6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22martians%22%20%22Mars%20and%20if%20inclined%20for%20a%20vacation%20excursion%22&f=false)," an address delivered by John Motley to the New-York Historical Society on December 16, 1868:

> In popular periodicals and lectures of to-day you may learn much of the bays, rivers, inlets, oceans, and continents of the planet Mars; and if inclined for a vacation excursion, and could you find a conveyance thither, you might easily arrange a tour in that planet, starting from Huggin's Inlet and sailing thirty thousand miles along one of its very convenient estuaries without ever losing sight of land. I know not whether the **Martians** have accepted the nomenclature of Dawes Continent, Table-Leg Bay, and the other designations laid down on their planet by the spirited geographer of ours; but at least they might be flattered did they know of the interest they excite on this earth.

Comment: I grant you that that’s indeed pretty early for the denizens of Mars. To me this seems an unremarkable use of an adjective to mean people from where that adjective describes. We speak of Martian geology because the adjective has always been *Martian*, all the way back until before English was English. The OED’s earliest such reference is from *The Canterbury Tales*: **“*c* 1395** Geoffrey Chaucer *Wife of Bath’s Tale* 610 I am al Venerien In feelyng, and myn herte is Marcien." So the sense meaning "of Mars" has always been there in the word.

Comment: "if inclined for a vacation excursion, and could you find a conveyance thither, you might easily arrange a tour in that planet, starting from Huggin's Inlet and sailing thirty thousand miles along one of its very convenient estuaries without ever losing sight of land." Indeed you would, but not in the way that author intended it.

Comment: The quoted first paragraph from its first sentence to its last one is very characteristic of scientific short-sightingness... (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_with_extraterrestrial_intelligence)

Answer (score 7):

OED - first recorded use:

> **Martian** n. **1.a. Science Fiction. An (imagined) inhabitant of Mars.**
>
> 1883   [W. S. Lach-Szyrma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._S._Lach-Szyrma) "Aleriel; or, a voyage to other worlds" iii. iii. 109   *He..brought with him another Martian, differently attired.*

The Blog, "The Worlds' First Martians - and First Martian Invasion" has an earlier reference:

> **[The Moons of Mars (Cornhill Magazine, v. 36, October **1877**](https://esnpc.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-worlds-first-martians-and-first.html), page 412).  The article goes on to describe the size of the moons and how those moons might look in the Martian sky to an observer standing on Mars:
>
> Thus the light given by the farther of his two moons varies from one two-hundredth to one three-hundredth part of our moon’s.  This part, then, of the Martian moonlight is but small in amount, and certainly cannot go far to compensate the Martians (as compared with us Terrestrials) for their greater distance from the sun.

Answer (score 7):

It's nothing unique to Mars, or to planets.  It's just one of the ways that English forms words for things/people that come from places.  E.g. Italian, Australian, &c.

So as soon as some English-speaking person* comes up with the idea that there might be people/intelligant beings living on the planet Mars, those people would almost automatically be referred to as Martians.

*Like H.G. Wells, though I'd be surprised to find that others hadn't predated him. If all you want is the first use, then the History or perhaps Literature sites would be better places to ask.

Comment: “*So as soon as some English-speaking person comes up with the idea that there might be people/intelligant beings living on the planet Mars, those people would almost automatically be referred to as Martians.*” that’s the heart of my question...when and where did that happen?..who came up with the idea and put it down in writing?

Comment: @Gio: Then the History, Literature, or perhaps Science Fiction sites would be better places to ask.

Answer (score 4):

"Martian" may not be a surprising choice of word, but it was not necessarily inevitable.  The astronomer Richard Proctor, who famously observed and wrote about Mars, used the name "Martialist" in 1867, before the earliest known examples of "Martian" in print in 1869 (from an address given in December 1868).

I wrote a blog post of several years ago with early examples of "Martian" in print, but I was not aware of several examples I've seen since from 1869/1870, and was not aware of the 1868 address mentioned in another response here.

But even through the 1870s, "Martian" was not a clear winner.  "Martialist" as a noun, "Martian" as an adjective, and "Martian being" as a noun all appeared in a series of articles in Cornhill Magazine between 1870 and 1877.  "Martian" was used by prominent British and American astronomers in 1877 during a particularly close flyby of Mars when moons of Mars were first seen.

From my [blogpost](https://esnpc.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-worlds-first-martians-and-first.html):

> Martial or Martian
>
> The transition from Martial as an adjective for describing things
> related to Mars played out in the pages of the influential British
> literary magazine, Cornhill Magazine, between 1871 through 1877.  The
> 1871 article, Life in Mars, used the same terminology used by Proctor,
> namely martial (adjective) and martialist (noun). Volume 23, May 1871.
> An 1873 article, The Planet Mars: an Essay by a Whewellite (v. 28,
> July 1873) uses both Martian and Martial as adjectives, while
> referring to possible life on Mars as beings or creatures.  An article
> from 1877, The Planet of War (v. 36, July 1877) uses Martian as an
> adjective exclusively, yet also refers to “Martian beings” as
> “Martialists.”  It would be only one small step (“one giant leap”
> seems more appropriate for the moon) to transition from “Martian
> beings” to “Martians.”

Comment: Very interesting answer—and excellent research. I note that an article from the _London Spectator_, reprinted in the _[Philadelphia] Evening Telegraph_ as "[Life in Mars](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025925/1870-06-17/ed-1/seq-6/#words=Martialist%2Bmartialist%2Bmartialist)" (June 17, 1870), discusses Proctor's "new work entitled 'Other Worlds Than Ours'" and uses the term "Martialists" at least five times and "a Martialist" at least once in reference to inhabitants of Mars.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective formed from Mars is *martial*, but that already has another meaning, so those sci fi writers had to invent something else to describe inhabitants of Mars.

Same for Venus -> *venereal* has another meaning, so we need another word to describe inhabitants of Venus.

Mercury -> *mercurial*, already used

Jupiter -> *jovial*, already used

Saturn -> *saturnine*, already used

Comment: No, not always. We speak of Martian geology and such. “**1950**   Aldous Huxley *Themes & Variations* 256   Man's Martian aggression against himself.”  Notice that means bellic, belligerent: of war, of Mars. Also: **“1994**   *Kindred Spirit* (Devon, U.K.) Autumn 46/1   I'm not really spacey about it, I'm very here and now, but it helps me to understand the Martian nature in me that wants to fight.”

Comment: The "-ial" ending means "like Mars". The "-ian" ending means something closer to "child of Mars".

Comment: @user7868 That is **not** what the two OED citations are illustrating there. Both use Martian to mean Mars-like. So did the Chaucer citation I provided on an another answer.

Comment: Martial refers to Mars the god, Martian refers to Mars the planet. Similarly Jovial refers to Jupiter the god, and Jovian refers to Jupiter the planet. Similarly Mercurian, Saturnian, etc.